# Error in sql query using CASE when applying formula to the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have to apply the fees on the amount column in the transaction table. If the amount is greater than `5000` then I have to apply `17.5` against **each transaction** and take the sum in the end. If the amount is less than 5000 then I have to apply the *percentage formula* on the amount and then take the sum of it in the end. Below is my query but I am getting the below exception:

```
SELECT 
        CASE  
        When tran_amount_req >= 5000 Then sum(17.5) 
        When tran_amount_req < 5000 Then sum(((tran_amount_req/100) * 0.35)/100) 
        End as MyPercent
        from gstl_trans_temp
        where (message_type_mapping = '0220') and card_type ='GEIDP1'
```

Column `gstl_trans_temp.tran_amount_req` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is very clear, what don't you understand about it?

Comment: And part of your WHERE-Clause looks suspicious and tran_amount_req >= 10000

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images). [mcve].

Comment: @Sergey you are right, it was by mistake, but error remains the same even after fixing it.

Comment: @HoneyBadger no, I don't understand how to fix it. Sorry, I am using CASE for the first time.

Comment: can you show us the expected output?

Comment: is not the `case` causing this error, is the `sum`, you can't use aggregate without proper `group by` or window function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want conditional aggregation as follows?

```
SELECT sum(CASE When tran_amount_req >= 5000 then 17.5 
                else ((tran_amount_req/100) * 0.35)/100 
           End) as MyPercent
 from gstl_trans_temp
where message_type_mapping = '0220' 
  and card_type ='GEIDP1'
```

Comment: Thanks alot sir, this is what I wanted.It really helped me understand the CASE.

Comment: just one more question, how can I pass MyPercent in a variable called let's say abc?